# Google+ hashtaging words with the hash symbol in it?

Tags: google-plus

In Google+, how can one hashtag the words containing hashes such as F#?

I tried writing `#F#`, but it captures `#F` leaving the trailing `#` separated.

Comment: https://twitter.com/dsyme If Don Syme uses #fsharp on Twitter, I think people would recognize the use of that on G+

Comment: (that doesn't really answer your question, though, so I will leave it as a comment and see if someone knows some way to escape the # character)

Comment: It solves my problem inasmuch as #fsharp is a recognized tag on google+, but as you say it doesn't really answer my question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

OK. By googling I found out that hashtags do not allow special characters, with the exception of the underscore character.

See for example: [here](http://sidewalkbranding.net/2013/07/12/hashtag-special-characters/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14823412/2582918)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar Q&A [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/111929/can-we-escape-a-word-in-a-google-to-avoid-conversion-to-a-hashtag/113123#113123). Here is a complete answer to avoid downvotes for linking to answers:

We need a "zero width space" character before the hash. For example ^#Foo (where the ^ is this special character described below) will not translate into a hashtag link.

This character is HTML &#8203; or Unicode U+200B. But you can't enter this directly in G+. The way to get this character depends on the application you're using, your system, and your fonts.

Method 1: In general, to enter this on your keyboard, make sure numlock is turned on, hold down the Alt key, enter 8203 on the numeric pad, then release the Alt key:

Alt+8203

It will insert the proper character, but you may see garbage depending on where you type this and the fonts. Some people report success with Alt+08203.

As an alternative, and the only option that seems to work for me right now: In Windows you can open the Character Map application. It's available in the Accessories start group, or by running charmap.exe.

[image: Windows charmap app]

You can copy U+200B like so: Activate advanced view and use the input field labelled "Go to Unicode". See above. Input 200B and the character will be highlighted. Click Select and Copy. Now the character is in your copy buffer. You can paste it into G+ as follows (of course ctrlV means you hit that keystroke at that point) :

"This is not a ctrlV#hashtag"

See [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/74636/24936) to a similar question on suppressing Twitter from converting hashtags and links.