# Can we "escape" a # word in a Google+ to avoid conversion to a hashtag?

Tags: google-plus, special-characters

Example : With some software the prefix of a pound-sign / hash / number symbol is significant. We don't want to it to be a hashtag. Here are a couple examples where I've tried to escape text so that it's not processed into hashcodes. The bolded text is processed, the others are not.

This should not be \#hashed.
No ##idea
Can I [#unhash] one or [#more **#than** **#one**] words?

While the text as seen does not get turned into a hash link, the syntax I'm using remains. I just want the text displayed, not linked.

Comment: Thanks, but not a winner. In my examples and that web page, all of the surrounding characters appear in the final text. When we escape text, the escape character/sequence should never appear. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I posted an [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/74636/24936) to this question a couple years ago. The trick is to use a "zero width space" character, in this case before the hash. So as documented in that other SE response, get unicode x200B from charmap.exe, then ctrl-v right before the #.